# Cannot GET after async AJAX request in reactjs react.Component

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, reactjs, components

I have a problem with my reactjs code. I've read the thread about the async world and the problems that can occur and I think I fix that, but now I get a blank with a text of Cannot GET /thenameofthepage.

This is my code right after the react.Component

```
getList() {
    var returnValue;
      $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: "###URL###",
        cache: false,
        async: false,
        success : function(data) {
         returnValue = data;
        }
      });

    return returnValue;
  }
```

and this is the code right after render() {

```
console.log(this.getList());
```

If I console log in the function then everything is okay. But when I try to pass it to a variable everything breaks. I did async. Not working. I tried with initial states and ComponentDidMount() again not working.

P.S

I tried by using internet guide:

```
constructor() {
    this.state = { data: [] };
  }
  getList() {
    $.ajax({
      type: "get",
      url: "http://havvamustafa.devel.signature.eu.com/manage/collection/list_all_ajax",
      cache: false,
      dataType: 'json',
      success: (data) => {
        this.setState({data: data});
      }
    });
  }
```

Then

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.getList();
  }
```

And in the end

```
console.log(this.state.data);
```

Now it gives me error because of the constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Jquery $.ajax's documentation, the use of `async: false` is deprecated

> async (default: true)
>
> Type: Boolean
>
> By default, all requests are sent asynchronously (i.e. this is set to true by default). If you need synchronous requests, set this option to false. Cross-domain requests and dataType: "jsonp" requests do not support synchronous operation. Note that synchronous requests may temporarily lock the browser, disabling any actions while the request is active. **As of jQuery 1.8, the use of async: false with jqXHR ($.Deferred) is deprecated; you must use the success/error/complete callback options instead of the corresponding methods of the jqXHR object such as jqXHR.done() or the deprecated jqXHR.success().**

I don't know what kind of problems do you think of when dealing with asynchronous data fetch, but don't forget that using **synchronous** requests freeze the browser while the request is pending. You could make it easier by doing :

```
getList() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "get",
    url: "###URL###",
    cache: false
  }).done(this.handleSuccess);
},

handleSuccess(results) {
  this.setState({data: results});
}
```

Your data processing is done in an other method, it will be cleaner !

Comment: Its not working. Or I am not doing it properly. I added your code. then added 
    getInitialState() {
    return { data : [] };
  }    
Then added :
componentDidMount() {
    this.getList;
  } 
And in the render 
if(jQuery.isEmptyObject(this.state.data)) {
      console.log("No data");
    } else {
      console.log(this.state.data);
    }

But again it gives me that blank page and the Cannot GET. If I try to go to the page via link then it the console it says : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of null

Comment: constructor() { super(); this.getList = this.getList.bind(this); this.state = { data: [] }; }.

Comment: It worked. Thank you. Thank you very much man. OMG Thank youuuu. <3 You are a life saver.

Comment: @g9m29: if this was the solution, please accept it. To do so, click on the tick icon on the left hand side, so that it turns green. This is how we mark questions as resolved here.